# Django upload image for current user for him cars

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-forms, django-views

I'm trying to create an image upload form with a car choices field that need to be done on the cars of the current dealer

**models**:

```
class Photo(BaseDateAuditModel):
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='photos/')
    position = models.SmallIntegerField(default=1, validators=[MinValueValidator(limit_value=1)])
    car = models.ForeignKey('cars.Car', on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='photos')

class Dealer(User):
    city = models.ForeignKey('City', on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, blank=False)

class Car(BaseDateAuditModel):
    properties = models.ManyToManyField(Property)

    objects = CarManager.from_queryset(CarQuerySet)()
    views = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0, editable=False)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=75)
    number = models.CharField(max_length=16, unique=True)

    dealer = models.ForeignKey("dealers.Dealer", on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='cars', null=True, blank=False)

    model = models.ForeignKey('CarModel', on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, blank=False)
    color = models.ForeignKey('Color', on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, blank=False)
```

**Form:**

```
class ImageForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Photo
        fields = ['image', 'car']
        widgets = {
            'image': forms.ClearableFileInput(attrs={'multiple': True}),
        }
```

**View:**

```
class UpdateImageView(FormView):
    model = Photo
    form_class = ImageForm
    template_name = 'image-update.html'

    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse('cars:cars-list')

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.save()
        return super().form_valid(form)  # 1st way, get list all car, not only for current user

    def get_queryset(self):
        '''
        return a list of cars of the current user
        for example: my current dealer(user) have one car and this
        method return:
            Car.objects.filter(id__in=car_list) == <CarQuerySet [<Car: Audi >]>
        '''
        user = self.request.user
        car_list = Dealer.objects.filter(username=user).values_list('cars', flat=True)
        return Car.objects.filter(id__in=car_list)
```

I thought about `def save()` and `get_initial` on Views and `get_initial_for_field` in Form, but dont understand how to implement them.

I'm new to python and your help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Forms:

```
class ImageForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, dealer_id, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ImageForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['car'].queryset = Car.objects.filter(dealer=dealer_id)

    class Meta:
        model = Photo
        fields = ['image', 'car']
        widgets = {
            'image': forms.ClearableFileInput(attrs={'multiple': True}),
        }
```

Views:

```
class UpdateImageView(FormView):
    model = Photo
    form_class = ImageForm
    template_name = 'image-update.html'

    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse('cars:cars-list')

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.dealer = self.request.user
        form.save()
        return super().form_valid(form)

    def get_form_kwargs(self):
        kwargs = super(UpdateImageView, self).get_form_kwargs()
        kwargs['dealer_id'] = self.request.user.pk
        return kwargs
```